# Как поменять кнопки на тачпаде

Tags: linux, archlinux, настройки, тач

После установки **Linux Arch** столкнулся с тем, что при нажатии левой кнопки тачпада - страница дополнительно прокручивается вниз, совершаются еще какие то действия. Решил проверить через xinput test. **Показало, что при нажатии, казалось бы, первой кнопки - нажимается пятая (или шестая. Или и 1, и 5, и 6)**. При просто нажатии на сам тачпад - нажимается как и надо первая кнопка.

Долго уже пытаюсь разобраться, но не могу понять, как же мне поменять эти кнопки местами. Копался в **xinput props, в synclient**, ничего не нашел.

Есть два варианта, первый - настроить, второй - обновить драйвера. И то и то я Не знаю как реализовать.
Надеюсь кто нибудь поможет

*тачпад соответственно synaptics*

Answer (score 0):

Может эмуляция включенна? посмотрите настройки тачпада

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]